# How do I make so when I click my checkbox, a separate and editable frame opens?

Tags: java, arrays, checkbox, frames

I am currently working with Java. I have made checkboxes and I would like to know how to make it so when the checkbox is clicked it opens a separate frame that can be modified and edited for my needs. I've heard that an array of frames/components would work. Any help/solutions would be appreciated.

Comment: Show us what you think the solution would be. From the sounds of it you need a listener for your checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question you must implement a listener for your checkbox.
And in the body of that listener, there should be something like this:

```
    //1. Create the frame.
JFrame frame = new JFrame("FrameDemo");

//2. Optional: What happens when the frame closes?
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

//3. Create components and put them in the frame.
//...create emptyLabel...
frame.getContentPane().add(emptyLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

//4. Size the frame.
frame.pack();

//5. Show it.
frame.setVisible(true);
```

The first and 5th points are **the most important**.

If you dont know how to create and register listener for checkbox, try to visit these sites:
http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/desktop-java/awt/event/checkbox-listener-example/
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html

I hope that this advice help you.